# Instagram API from client side

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, instagram

I'm trying to call Instagram API endpoints from the client side.  I can only access GET-based endpoints using JSONP, which [Instagram recommends](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/).  For those requiring POST or DELETE, it seems CORS isn't enabled, so these types of ajax calls fail.

Is there any method or approach I can use to access these APIs from the client side?

Comment: hidden forms can post, but you can't get a return value there, so it might not be any use to you. however, you might work around a lack of return by running another GET and seeing if anything changed to detect success manually.

Comment: I just tested POST with JSONP. It does work.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible to make POST calls directly from client side, You have to setup a proxy server that makes the Instagram API calls for POST and DELETE, and your client side app can call the proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

I not understand your question, but i use the Instagram API in Client Side, and i make POST and GET, using it:

```
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  "method": "POST",

  //Use the URL in Instagram Document
  url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/<ID>/likes?access_token=<TOKEN>',
  dataType: "jsonp", 

  //To get response
  success: function(result){

  //Exemple, if is okay or not
  if(result.meta.code == 200){
  alert('ok');  
  }else{
  alert('fail'); 
  }

  }
});
```

You can change the token and media id, and test it on http://jsfiddle.net/DvLE2/

If you need send data (action, in relationship), you add:

```
data: data;
```

Exemple, for Relationship (to follow or unfollow someone):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      "method": "POST",

      url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<ID>/relationship?access_token=<TOKEN>',
      //action (you need that to use relationship 
      data: {action: 'follow'},
      dataType: "jsonp", 
      success: function(result){
      if(result.meta.code == 200){
      alert('ok');

      }else{
      alert('fail');
      }

      }
    });
```

Comment: Your can't make POST requests with JSONP.  Your `type` option should be "GET"