# EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL:

Tags: angular, jsonp, instagram-api

I am trying to use the instagram api to get some photo.
Unfortunately, it seems that it is a little hard to cope with [its](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847070/instagram-api-from-client-side) CORS problem.
So i made my mind to use `Jsonp.get` to pass it.

Here is my service:

```
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Gallery} from './gallery';
import {Jsonp} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class InstagramService{

    constructor( private _http:Http,private _jsonp: Jsonp ){           

    }

    getGallery(username: string) : Observable<Gallery> {

        return this._jsonp.get("https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media/" ).map(res =>  res.json());                                                                            
    }
}
```

The problem is, when i run my code i face with the error:

```
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 200 Ok for URL: https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media/
```

So what is this error?
How can i fix it?

Point:
I am using the url:

```
https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media/
```

It does not need authentication, you can try it in your browser or postman.
And i am only interested to `Get` request so i do not need `post` or etc.

Comment: jsonp is not supported for that URL, since u are doing on server side, just do regular http.get, it should work

Comment: @krisrak  when i use hhtp.get it complains with cors. and there is nothing i can do with cors. iis there?

Comment: it should work, i have used same url with python with no issues, CORS is an issue when u are making call on client side using javascript, but on server side it should not be an issue

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @user5363938 have you solved this problem? It is occurring with me too, and i don't know what do.

Answer (score 0):

your implementation of `jsonp` looks fine. what your are missing is listing them as `providers` similar to `HTTP_PROVIDERS` like this in your component:

```
import {JSONP_PROVIDERS, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    //...
    providers : [JSONP_PROVIDERS]
});
```

then you can consume observable using `subscribe`.

Comment: it is a service so there is no component

Comment: Then try adding it in `bootstrap` method in `main.ts` file.

Comment: did it help ? @user5363938

Comment: Unfortunately, Not.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the two solutions

1. https://www.instagram.com/justinbieber/media/

   getResponse().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");

   _jsonp --->  http
2. change the json string
   example:

   old string:"{id:1,name:32}"

   new string:"**__ng_jsonp__.__req1.finished(**{id:1,name:32}**)**"